# Calling a method from another class using TestNG and Java

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, webdriver, testng

Getting an error below after running test2.java running as TestNG if I run it as Java Application everything is working.  What does the error mean and can anyone help me with this using TestNG and Java.  I am using Webdriver and Eclipse and just want to do this simple trick to apply for my test scripts.

> SKIPPED: main org.testng.TestNGException:  Method main requires 1
>   parameters but 0 were supplied in the @Test annotation.

Here is my code for Test1.java

```
package firsttestngpackage;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test
public class Test1{
    public void message(){
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

Here is my code for Test2.java

```
package firsttestngpackage;

import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test
public class Test2{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test1 class1 = new Test1();
        class1.message();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `@Test` in the class level, all the public methods are considered test methods. You need to supply `parameters` to the main method as it expects an argument.

Just change it to `public void main()`

Comment: Doesn't that only apply to methods returning void, though?

Answer (score 1):

It looks you are using TestNG in wrong way. You don't need java main method. Just use annotation @Test and then run class with TestNG (`org.testng.TestNG`) and defined .xml test suite as Java Application or in Eclipse runner. TestNG invokes all tests methods so you don't have to call it manually.

Answer (score 0):

i got it to work by removing "String[] args"

```
package firsttestngpackage;

import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test
public class Test2{
    public void main(){
        Test1 class1 = new Test1();
        class1.message();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jaroslav is right.you are using @Test annotation in a wrong way.While using testNG framework u r not using the main method to run the test.u running it as TestNG tests

Comment: Yes thank you.  You guys are right I do not use the main method in my TestNG tests.  I was able to call method from a different class w/o using the main method.  So basically replace main() to something else and it works too.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the above comments are right. Don't use main method if you are using testNG annotations. Main method can only be used in `@Beforeclass` and `@Afterclass`. Also no need of `(String[] args)`.

If you are still facing problem with TestNg,

1. Make sure you have installed it correctly.
2. Use this code before your 1st test case (`@Test`)

`@BeforeTest

        public void setup ()
        {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "*location of your driver*");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("test-type");
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc");

        options.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info"); 
        options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
        options.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");
        options.addArguments("test-type=browser");
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    }`

Let me know if this helps.